# Unable to use jar file inside docker container when downloaded

Tags: docker, dockerfile, open-telemetry

**Context:** I'm trying to use opentelemetry-javaagent in my spring project.

If I get the file using curl in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/download/v1.30.0/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -o /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar && \
    chmod 540 /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
```

When I run the docker image I get the following error:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

However, if I manually download that exact file and add it:

```
ADD opentelemetry-javaagent.jar /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
RUN chmod 540 /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
```

It works fine. I'm probably missing something obvious but can't put my finger on it. Does anyone know what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Here is the full Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre

ARG RUN_JAVA_VERSION=1.3.8
ENV APP my-project
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-XshowSettings:vm"
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker


ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=10200,server=y,suspend=n -javaagent:/tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.service.name=format-adapter -Dotel.traces.exporter=zipkin

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update -q \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget curl \
    && rm -Rf /var/lib/apt /var/cache/apt


RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/run-java-sh/${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}/run-java-sh-${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}-sh.sh -o /app/run-java.sh && \
    chmod 540 /app/run-java.sh


#THIS DOESN'T WORK
RUN curl https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/download/v1.30.0/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -o /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar && \
    chmod 540 /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar

##THIS WORKS
#ADD opentelemetry-javaagent.jar /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
#RUN chmod 540 /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar

ADD build/libs/${APP}-*.jar /app/${APP}.jar

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost:${SERVER_PORT}/actuator/health || exit 1

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/run-java.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given URL generates a redirect that `curl` does not follow unless you add the `-L` switch, so the `curl` command in your `Dockerfile` does not download anything.

As an alternative, `wget` follows redirects by default (I see that you install both `curl` and `wget` but the base image already contains both); however a better, `Dockerfile`-specific, alternative is the [`ADD` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

```
ADD --chmod=540 https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/download/v1.30.0/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
```

In any case you can remove the `RUN apt-get` block to get a smaller image.